# Why load-path duplicates?

Tags: init-file, package

This are the first 4 lines of my `init.el`

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

After loading emacs all the entries (`elpa/package.version`) added by `package-initialize` to the load-path are in it twice, once without a trailing slash and once with it.

Does anyone know why it does this? Won't it slow things down by searching the directories twice?

It made me think I was adding them to the load path twice, but I'm not.

Comment: Are you loading any packages that automatically set the load-paths in your init file. Perhaps this is happening in another part of the init file. package-initialize only loads with a trailing /, so something else is adding those paths. Even if speed is not an issue, some search tools redundantly show multiple hits for the same hit, once for each path.

Comment: I don't think so. Even if I comment out everything but those 4 lines I get the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these lines to avoid duplicate paths in load-path after package-initialize:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

Not providing the t value to add-to-list as optional APPEND argument avoids duplicate load-paths. To add-to-list to the end of the list without using the t value, then use this **variation**:

```
(require 'package)
(reverse (cons '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") (reverse 'package-archives)))
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

Comment: That puts melpa first on the package-archives list. I don't know why that fixes the duplicates, but thank you very much. The melpa guys should change the instructions on their [getting started page](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started)